# Hierachical Bayesian modelling using brms: how to insert a prior that reflects cut-offs of Reaction Times distribution?

Tags: prior, hierarchical-bayesian, brms

I am running a hierarchical Bayesian model using brms on reaction times (RTs) of a GoNogo task. The predictors are categorical and include the 3 stimuli/condition that participants observed and the 2 sequences of trials.
I used an ex-Gaussian distribution for RTs.

here is the model:

```
informed1_RTs.bmodel = brm(RTs  ~  conditionStimuli * sequenceTrials + (0 + conditionStimuli * sequenceTrials | Num_part)
                          , data = data_RTs_go
                          , family = exgaussian(link = "identity")
                          , warmup = 500
                          , iter = 2000                         
                          , chains = 2
                          , inits = "random"
                          , cores = 2
                          , seed = 123
                          , save_pars = save_pars(all = TRUE)
                          )
```

The pp_check shows a good fit (I think!) but the edges exceed the cut-off of the RTs (I chose a lower cutoff of 200ms and an upper cut-off o 750). I expect that inserting a boundary in the distribution reflecting the cut-off would improve the model predictions.

How do I insert such a boundary? Following Gelman, 2006 I tried to insert a uniform(200,750) but it gives various warnings and errors that the boundaries are not possible.

Thank you,

this is an example of the data:

```
Num_part trial_type  Go_type conditionStimuli ITI_ms response RTs correctResponse order_pres sequenceTrials sdt
2        1         Go     Bent           leaves    819        1 301               1          1            NGG   1
3        1         Go     Bent           leaves    771        1 237               1          1             GG   1
4        1         Go     Bent           leaves   1086        1 393               1          1             GG   1
5        1         Go Straight           leaves    652        1 331               1          1             GG   1
7        1         Go     Bent           leaves    919        1 372               1          1            NGG   1
9        1         Go Straight           leaves    802        1 359               1          1            NGG   1
```

[image: the pp_check function reflecting how the model prediction fit the actual data. The observed data have a cutoff at 750 ms, which is not respected in the prediction of the model]